# I want to push my GitLab code on my website server using gitlab ci and ssh but it doesn't work correctly when I pull

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-pull

I have made this .gitlab-ci.yml to push my code automatically on my webserver:

```
stages:
    - deploy

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    image: ubuntu:latest
    environment:
        name: production
    only:
        - master
    before_script:
        - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
        - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
        - apt-get install -y -qq git
        - export SSHPASS=$AddressServerWebSSHPwd
    script:
        - sshpass -e ssh -p 22 $AddressServerWebSSH cd www/web-jjb && ls -auxl && git pull origin master && echo "test" && ls -auxl
```

Everything works, the ssh connections are correct, the pull also until the result.
If I look on the log of the pipeline, the pull work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ILo.png

But when I look on fileZilla, there are nothing... (He is supposed to add index.php):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg0NI.png

Somebody got an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another sftp client

It seems a Filezilla caching issue, but, if you close and reopen it, the cache will be updated

Comment: Okay, I have try, It doesn't work...
And I have try with ssh in powershell and index.php is not present....

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have why It dosn't works. When He execute :
`- sshpass -e ssh -p 22 $AddressServerWebSSH cd www/web-jjb && ls -auxl && git pull origin master && echo "test" && ls -auxl`

After the first `&&`, He close the ssh connection.

The right way to do it is : `sshpass -e ssh -p 22 $AddressServerWebSSH git -C www/web-jjb pull origin master`